# XDocument how to search by xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a xml file like below, i want to find the node which property "name" value equals "ImageListView"

I have writen below code:

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("asmv1", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");
xpath = "//asmv1:assembly/dependency/dependentAssembly/assemblyIdentity[name='ImageListView']";
XElement ele = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath, nsmgr);
ele.Remove();
```

but cannot find anything. is any wrong here? thanks.

Comment: You wrote: `I have an xml file like below`. Where is your xml file?

Comment: Try `.//asmv1:assembly...`, if I remember correctly, providing `.` will look for that node everywhere inside the structure

Comment: http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Comment: Is the `name` property an element or an attribute?

Comment: my sample file at here:https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=EFE5B57ED9781C46&id=EFE5B57ED9781C46%21817

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XML has default namespace here :

```
<asmv1:assembly 
    ......
    xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" 
    ......>
```

Therefore, all XML element without prefix considered in default namespace. You need to add prefix that point to default namespace URI, and use it in XPath :

```
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("asmv1", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1");
nsmgr.AddNamespace("d", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2");
xpath = "//asmv1:assembly/d:dependency/d:dependentAssembly/d:assemblyIdentity[@name='ImageListView']";
XElement ele = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath, nsmgr);
ele.Remove();
```

**UPDATE :**

fixed the XPath slightly. You need to use `@` to point to attribute : `... [@name='ImageListView']`